# Not Getting JSON output as in the demo of watson personality insight

Tags: java, android, jsonp, ibm-watson

Building a simple personality insight android application using its java sdk, I was not able to get the required JSON output as in the demo.

```
public class Analysis extends AppCompatActivity {

private String textAnalysis;
PersonalityInsights service;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_analysis);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    textAnalysis = intent.getStringExtra("data");
    Log.i("DATA",textAnalysis+" ff");
    service = new PersonalityInsights();
           service.setUsernameAndPassword(getString(R.string.user_id),getString(R.string.password));


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Profile profile = service.getProfile(textAnalysis+"").execute();
            Log.i("Analysis",profile.toString());
            Trait trait = profile.getTree();
            Log.i("Analysis","Categories"+trait.getCategory());
            Log.i("Analysis","Name"+trait.getName());
            Log.i("Analysis","Children"+trait.getChildren().get(1).getName());
            Log.i("Analysis","Percentage"+trait.getPercentage());
        }
    }).start();

}
  }
```

But the output is different from that of demo. It didn't had the Big 5 Personality traits,needs,value and other things

```
"children": [ {
     "children": [
     {
       "category": "personality",
       "children": [
         {
           "category": "personality",
           "children": [
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Adventurousness",
        "name": "Adventurousness",
        "percentage": 0.6702837479298441,
        "sampling_error": 0.0498460567
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Artistic interests",
        "name": "Artistic interests",
        "percentage": 0.8054407502066927,
        "sampling_error": 0.1015761071
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Emotionality",
        "name": "Emotionality",
        "percentage": 0.46526949977539345,
        "sampling_error": 0.046778333500000005
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Imagination",
        "name": "Imagination",
        "percentage": 0.1636949533378917,
        "sampling_error": 0.0624994068
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Intellect",
        "name": "Intellect",
        "percentage": 0.9963456758072283,
        "sampling_error": 0.0546178831
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Liberalism",
        "name": "Authority-challenging",
        "percentage": 0.7512306650873422,
        "sampling_error": 0.0818740146
      }
           ],
           "id": "Openness",
           "name": "Openness",
           "percentage": 0.9927226873432959,
           "sampling_error": 0.0584048909
         },
         {
           "category": "personality",
           "children": [
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Achievement striving",
        "name": "Achievement striving",
        "percentage": 0.7368742460200748,
        "sampling_error": 0.0963623238
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Cautiousness",
        "name": "Cautiousness",
        "percentage": 0.9743850469356967,
        "sampling_error": 0.0897570103
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Dutifulness",
        "name": "Dutifulness",
        "percentage": 0.9146327962074232,
        "sampling_error": 0.059146664099999996
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Orderliness",
        "name": "Orderliness",
        "percentage": 0.42552691130776477,
        "sampling_error": 0.0686670938
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Self-discipline",
        "name": "Self-discipline",
        "percentage": 0.6471345466162,
        "sampling_error": 0.0459092878
      },
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "id": "Self-efficacy",
        "name": "Self-efficacy",
        "percentage": 0.5770567155207881,
        "sampling_error": 0.0900573954
      }
           ],
           "id": "Conscientiousness",
           "name": "C

09-18 06:37:28.688 17768-18972/com.jain.rakshit.personalityanalysis I/Analysis: Categoriesnull
09-18 06:37:28.688 17768-18972/com.jain.rakshit.personalityanalysis I/Analysis: Nameroot
09-18 06:37:28.688 17768-18972/com.jain.rakshit.personalityanalysis I/Analysis: ChildrenNeeds
09-18 06:37:28.688 17768-18972/com.jain.rakshit.personalityanalysis I/Analysis: Percentagenull
```

Answer (score 0):

The API always returns the profile with the 3 models, Big5, needs and values.

Calling a `toString()` method in the `Profile` object should print the entire JSON response.

I think the problem here is that you don't understand the JSON output. Take a look at the [API Reference](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v2/?java#profile), the JSON output is described there.

You can also test the API and get live results using the [API Explorer](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/personality-insights-v2).

Comment: Even after profile.toString() the JSON result was not similar to the personality insight demo json

Comment: can you point it out the differences ? I want to see both JSONs if possible

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v2/#profile in the end the required response is there and i did mentioned my JSON above in the the question

Comment: I just tested by calling `profile.toString()` and I'm able to get the same output as the one in the page you just shared